# Is there any way i can get focused props in tabBarBadgeStyle so that i can set background color accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Is there any way i can get focused props in tabBarBadgeStyle so that i can set background color accordingly.

```
          options={{
            tabBarLabel: "Teams",
            tabBarBadge: '3',
            tabBarBadgeStyle: { backgroundColor: ORANGE },
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
              <FontAwesome name="group" size={scale(15)} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
```

as we get focused in tabBarIcon

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this example it might help you.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const CustomTabBarIcon = ({ focused, color, size, badgeCount }) => {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  const badgeStyle = isFocused ? { backgroundColor: 'orange' } : {};

  return (
    <FontAwesome
      name="group"
      size={size}
      color={color}
    />
  );
};

export default CustomTabBarIcon;

import CustomTabBarIcon from './CustomTabBarIcon';

...

options={{
  tabBarLabel: 'Teams',
  tabBarBadge: '3',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
    <CustomTabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      color={color}
      size={size}
    />
  ),
}}
```

Please note that the above approach assumes the usage of React Navigation 5.x or later and the @react-navigation/native package

Regards,

Mahesh A.

Comment: this wont work ... i guess you are suggesting to show custom view at tabBarIcon with text as badge count